# PHP: remove word from sentence if it contains @

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace

I want to remove words from sentence if word contains **@**, I am using **php**.

**Input:** Hi I am **@RaghavSoni**

**Output:** Hi I am

Thank You.

Comment: I want to create the new Facebook. Thank you. (*have you tried anything yourself?*)

Comment: Yes, Not getting the required result.

Comment: Your looking for a regular expression. Nothing more until we see what you've tried

Comment: *What* have you tried yourself? *Why* doesn't it work? It helps you a lot more if we can explain where you went wrong so you don't make the same mistake again rather than spoonfeed you code.

Comment: I am not good in Regular Expression, can you please write the code here.

Comment: @RaghavSoni And you'll never get better if you don't try yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
$str = preg_replace('/@\w+/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while(strpos($string, '@') !== false) {

    $location1 = strpos($string, "@");
    $location2 = strpos($string, " ", $location1);

    if($location2 !== false) {
        $length = $location2 - $location1;

        $string1 = substr($string, 0, $location1);
        $string2 = substr($string, $location2);
        $string = $string1 . $string2;
    }
}

echo $string;
```

Comment: `The user @foo and the user @bar walked into a forrest` would only fix the first one.

Comment: @h2ooooooo that's very true! I suppose you could count the @ and loop

Comment: With this method you could also place the whole thing in a `while (($location1 = strpos($string, '@')) !== false) {`. [**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/VGhiIYF7).

Comment: @h2ooooooo even better.  fixing now

Comment: You might want to fix the memory leak with `strpos($string, ' ', $location1)` in case there's a username in the end of the string (simply check if `$location2 !== false`). There's also no reason to use `strpos` twice.

Comment: I'm starting to wish I had reason to use this code... :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good way, but it works :

```
<?php
$input="Hi I am @RaghavSoni";
$inputWords = explode(' ', $input);
foreach($inputWords as $el)
{
    if($el[0]=="@" )
    {
        $input = str_replace($el, "", $input);
    }
}
echo $input;
 ?>
```

Comment: Yes, but It takes more time.

Comment: I know, there should be a simple way, without loop,if statement and replace function.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo str_replace("@RaghavSoni", "", "Hi I am @RaghavSoni.");
# Output: Hi I am.
```

Comment: and what if you're looking to remove it for @code360?

Comment: @RaghavSoni this remove #Jacob Raccuia

Comment: @code360 No? Replacing `@RaghavSoni` does not remove `@code360`?